# Magento 2 - How to reload cart summary section

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart

I try following js code to reload cart summary section.

```
 <script>
     require(['jquery',
             'jquery/ui',
             'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
             'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
     ], function($,
                 quote,
                 totalsDefaultProvider){
         "use strict";
           jQuery(document).ready( function() {
               jQuery(".item_shipping").change(function(){
                   alert("Page loaded.");
                   totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
               })
           });
       });
```

> Following error give on console 
>    TypeError: options is undefined  return
>    $.getJSON(options.sectionLoadUrl, parameters).fail(function (jqXHR) {

Answer (score 3):

you need to add following code in your js file

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data'
], function($, getTotalsAction, customerData){
    'use strict';
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery(".item_shipping").change(function(){
            var deferred = $.Deferred();
            getTotalsAction([], deferred);
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: How can i get Total Value from this getTotalsAction([], deferred);

Comment: i have add this code in my custom js but got an error of getTotalsAction how can i solve that @Chirag Gondaliya?

Comment: not worked for me

Comment: how to reload the summary in admin

Answer (score 0):

One can try the below code (Tested on the cart page only):

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/cache'
], function($, quote, totalsProcessor, cartCache){
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $(".item_shipping").change(function(){
            cartCache.clear('cartVersion');
            totalsProcessor.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
        })
    });
});
```